# What's a multivariate Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, terminology, hidden-markov-model

I suppose "multivariate" refers to a function w/ multiple inputs. What function? One that, given an output sequence of a HMM, returns the probability distribution of state switch sequences of the HMM for the output? Something else?

Suppose we've 3 outputs: `ax`, `ab`, `Ax`. Would a multivariate (bivariate) HMM rather refer to `f(ax, ab)` or `d(character, capitalization)`? The first would define a probability (distribution) of state switch sequence(s), the second a set of output symbols. Of course, both would be equivalent to monovariant HMMs (e.g. the first to two evaluations of a unary function computing the same state switch probability (distribution) for `ax` and `ab`, the second to a function over an extended character set)

Answer (score 3):

We usually call multivariate HMM an HMM that model multidimensional observations.

If you have time series in the form:

X = [1 2 3 4 5 1 2] (each value corresponding to a time step), you will model them using a univariate HMM (as only one variable varies)

If the time series you are modeling have the form:
X = [1 2 3 4 5 1 2; 5 4 3 2 1 5 4] (i.e., a matrix with 2 rows, with each column corresponding to a time step), you will model them using a multivariate HMM (as you are observing multiple variables - 2 in this case).

The dimensions of your observations defines the dimension of the emission probability distributions used in the HMM.

Comment: OK.. then my example w/ `d(character,capitalization)` would describe a multivariate HMM? In the last sentence, did you mean "...defines the dimensions of the emission..."?

Comment: @jaam - An HMM has hidden states. Each hidden state is associated with a probability mass function (discrete case) or a probability distribution function (continuous case). This is what is also called "emission distribution" (the distribution are assumed to generate/emit the observations). The transition between the hidden states is modeled by a transition matrix which has nothing related to the distributions functions assigned to the hidden states.

Comment: @jaam - I suggest you to read this: http://ai.stanford.edu/~pabbeel/depth_qual/Rabiner_Juang_hmms.pdf
It should answer your concerns with some very concrete examples. Best introduction to HMMs that I know ;)

Comment: Consider a matrix `[a, ..., z; lowercase, uppercase]`. As long as `character` and `capitalization` are types and `d` a function variable, the matrix is clearly computable by some `d(character,capitalization)`. Thus,  some `d(character,capitalization)` would describe a multivariate HMM. If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

In a **univariate** hidden Markov model, one emission corresponds to one random variable, whereas in a **mulivariate** hidden Markov model, one emission corresponds to several random variables.

Comment: "Correspond" is vague. Do you mean that variables are state switch sequences, and a multivariate HMM maps multiple state switch sequences to an emission? In a multivariate HMM, does _every_ emission correspond to multiple state switch sequences? Or do you mean that the multiple variables the emission can correspond to are e.g. `x`, `uppercase`?